# Access virtualbox guest ubuntu localhost:8080 from windows host. Have NAT as well as Host-Only adapters

Tags: google-app-engine, ubuntu, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu on virtualbox, running google app engine on it which starts a server on localhost:8080. Now I want to test it using my host windows browser (I run the Ubuntu without GUI and would like to continue that way).

I have a host only adapter configured with the static ip 192.168.56.101. I have a NAT adapter as well.

Now I ASSUMED that i would be able to access the app engine server running on my guest ubuntu localhost:8080 by 192.168.56.101:8080 from my host Windows. Doesn't seem to work though.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you used the --address= argument of the SDK? From the doc: The host address to use for the server. You may need to set this to be able to access the development server from another computer on your network. An address of 0.0.0.0 allows both localhost access and hostname access. Default is localhost. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver

Comment: That works!! I tried '-a 192.168.56.101'. Thanks!!